# What Exceptions can PostAsJsonAsync throw?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception

Hi i would like to catch possible exceptions that PostAsJsonAsync can throw. I cannot find any exception information on the microsoft website about possible exceptions this method can throw. i would like to handle any possible exceptions.

Comment: @JohnSaunders perhaps he wants to catch and re-throw with more domain-specific information.

Comment: @josh then he should have answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe since it's an extension of `HttpClient` the exceptions it throws should be or inherit from [HttpRequestException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

According [this](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientExtensions.cs), it's just a wrapper for `HttpClient.PostAsync(String, HttpContent, CancellationToken)`, which throws only `ArgumentNullException` [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh551741%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)